# Looking for software to replace our communication board

Tags: windows

Currently we have a communication board in our lab. This board contains a grid of the 22 machining cells that we have at the facility. For each cell we put down the part number that is running, the status of the machine, and then we list out the times that each test is brought into the lab. This helps us track when our parts are brought in, which tests have been completed, and which ones we missed. Each cell gets tested every 4 hours, so in a 24 hour period we are supposed to test 6 wheels. It could be more or less depending on circumstances. I want to take this white board and have it moved to a digital medium. The idea is that there be a tablet that uses a program to enter new parts into the grid when they enter the lab. Then we would have a monitor to display the grid and have it update it as wheels are entered into the system. It is not pertinent that the data be saved for a long period of time, but it would be nice to be able to track the history of the cell. Is there any software that could help out here or is this more of a custom job? Below is a mockup I did in excel that I was trying to get to work with macros.
[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure, but sounds like custom or excel with macros or maybe airtable.com